# Converting Decimal (Double) Value < 0.001 to String in Java

Tags: java, double, tostring

I have written a small method which is utilised for most of the Object to String conversions.

```
public String str(Object object) {
    return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
}
```

When passing `double d = 0.0003` to this method, I get an output of `3.0E-4`. So I have altered the method like this.

```
public String str(Object object) {
    return object == null ? "" : object instanceof Double && (double) object < 0.001 ? String.format("%.10f", object)
            : object.toString();
}
```

But I kinda feel bad to check `instanceof` for every conversions which is an additional check for non double objects. Is this the only way that I can convert double to exact string value or is it possible to convert correctly without an additional instance of check. Since if the object satisfies `instanceof Double`, casting is of free cost and so I'm not worried about performance on casting.

I tried these steps, all produces `E` output except `String.format`

```
double d = 0.0003;               // 3.0E-4
System.out.println(String.valueOf(d));          // 3.0E-4
System.out.println(Double.toString(d));         // 3.0E-4
System.out.println(String.format("%.10f", d));   // 0.0003000000
```

Comment: The difference in performance is going to be unnoticeable, unless your method is being invoked thousands of times per second.  And possibly not even then.  In general, it's best not to worry about performance unless and until you have a performance issue.

Comment: Returning "" for `null` is a really really bad idea.

Comment: @EJP, I've to return "" for null value in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can provide different functions, for different types, like:

```
public static String str(final Object object) {
    return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
}

public static String str(final Double d) {
    return d == null ? "" : str(d.doubleValue());
}

public static String str(final double d) {
    return d < 0.001 ? String.format("%.10f", d) : String.valueOf(d);
}
```

Comment: This will also print in wrong format as the double is casted to Object first by the user.

Comment: Damn..! I've written most of the methods as method overloading, but didn't think of overloading by Double argument..! Silly me.. :D

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar you're right, in this case instanceof is the only way

Comment: @TheCoder as said earlier, this is not going to help you in this case.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar, It'll help. I've just reassigned it to Object just for the sake of trying it (in my last code). But the real passing argument will be `Double`. Deleted the line where Object reassignment is done. Anyhow, Thanks..

Comment: @TheCoder How is this solving the issue here? Why select this as answer?  Just curious.

Comment: @TheCoder okay. Seems like the question was more ambiguous then. Maybe better question would surely help clearing this confusion

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar, I've clearly said that I've passed `double d = 0.0003` into the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.valueOf()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> doubleValues = new ArrayList<>();
    double value = 0.0;
    doubleValues.add("5.01");
    doubleValues.add("0.002");
    doubleValues.add("0.00024");
    doubleValues.add("0.000022");

    for (String elem : doubleValues) {
        value += Double.valueOf(elem);
    }
    System.out.printf("%.10f", value); // Formatting in print
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(String.format("%.10f", value)); // Print with String formatting

    double v = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(value)); //convert decimal number to double for print or calc
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps separate the code that does the job from the test cases for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class PrintNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printNumberWOScientificNotations(0.1);
        printNumberWOScientificNotations(0.001);
        printNumberWOScientificNotations(0.00001);
        System.out.println(0.00001);
    }

    static void printNumberWOScientificNotations(Object number) {
        // Check if in scientific notation
        if (String.valueOf(number).toLowerCase().contains("e")) {
            System.out.println("Converting from e to number with 25 maximum fraction digits.");
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
            formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(25);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(new Double(number.toString())));
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(number));
        }
    }
}
```